# How do I check if a string contains a string from an array of strings?

Tags: c#, string

So here is my example

```
string test = "Hello World, I am testing this string.";
string[] myWords = {"testing", "string"};
```

How do I check if the string test contains any of the following words? If it does contain how do I make it so that it can replace those words with a number of asterisks equal to the length of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool cont = false;
string test = "Hello World, I am testing this string.";
string[] myWords = { "testing", "string" };
foreach (string a in myWords)
{
    if( test.Contains(a))
    {
        int no = a.Length;
        test = test.Replace(a, new string('*', no));
    }
}
```

Comment: So how do I make it so that it would change those words into astericks equal to the length of the word that was supposed to be filtered?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex:

```
public string AstrixSomeWords(string test)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\w+\b");

    return regex.Replace(test, AsterixWord);
}

private string AsterixWord(Match match)
{
    string word = match.Groups[0].Value;
    if (myWords.Contains(word))
        return new String('*', word.Length);   
    else
        return word;
}
```

I have checked the code and it seems to work as expected.

If the number of words in myWords is large you might consider using HashSet for better performance.

Comment: +1 for checking word boundaries - the other solutions would also match `"test"`, which is probably not intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
var containsAny = myWords.Any(x => test.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
foreach (var word in mywords){

    if(test.Contains(word )){

        string astr = new string("*", word.Length);

        test.Replace(word, astr);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Refined

Comment: You should use [`new string('*', word.Length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Never knew that existed. Thanks.